# How to sort data frame by multiple columns with considering submatrix column

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, sorting

input data frame

[image]

Need to sort by 2020-12-03
code like
`post_df.sort_values(by=['Post_Name','Post_Type','Submetric','2020-12-03'], ascending=False)`
but it not working ,  need to sort by leatest date.

Comment: please share the expected output after sorting dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to sort by the column '2020-12-03', you don't need to pass into `sort_values` the other columns...:

```
post_df.sort_values(by='2020-12-03', ascending=False)
```

Otherwise, your question is not very clear.